# Discrete Time Markov Chain - Inventory

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $D_n$ be the demand for an item at a store on day $n$. Suppose that $D_n$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables with probability mass function:

$p_k = P(D_n = k)$

Suppose the store follows the following inventory management policy. If inventory at
the end of the $n$th day (i.e., after satisfying the demands during the day) is above $s$ the store does nothing. If it is less than $s$, then the store orders enough amount to bring inventory at the beginning of the next day up to $S$. Assume the inventory delivery is instantaneous. Let $X_n$ be the amount of inventory in the store at the beginning of the $n$th day. Model $X_n$ as a DTMC.

Not sure how to deal with the probability mass function. I guess it would mean its equal but not sure how to put that in any other way rather than $p_k$. Nor do I understand how to deal with S.

Comment: I'd suggest thinking about what the possible states are, and what classes of transitions between them there are. If stock started at S and is above s, then would X be S less the sum of the demands since the last restock. If X is less than s, then the next day it is S and we can make an a priori argument about the probability of that happening.

Comment: what do you mean by classes of transition? I think there's stuff about symmetry, transitivity etc which I've not yet read up on. is it that?